# Benefits of using xargs

Tags: xargs

Let's say, I run a find command without xargs

```
find . -iname 'connect*' > cat output.txt
```

Question:1. How to copy the output of find command to a text file using xargs command?
2. What is advantage here on using the `xargs` command instead of just using `>`

I tried the below one and it doesnt seems to be correct.

```
find . -iname 'connect*'  | xargs -t cat > output.txt
```

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate the *names* of the files, or their *contents*?

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` takes strings from stdin and a command line on its own command line. It runs the command line using the strings from stdin as arguments to the command line. It's basically doing indirection. If you have a list of filenames (such as `find` produces) you can performa operations on the individual files (or their contents) with `xargs`. Like getting a top-20 word frequency list from a number of text files:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs cat | tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1.1nr | head -20
```

I'm not sure it's worthwhile to perform your task from Question 1. I'm certain that it can be done, but why bother? And that's the answer to question 2: there is no advantage either in performance or clarity of intention.

In general, the advantage of using `xargs` is that you can do elaborate things to decide which file names to put on its stdin. Your `find` could have time-of-creation added to it, or more than one name glob, or whatever. Just having a static list of filenames negates any advantage you might get from `xargs`: you'd be better off using `cat` or running the command `xargs` would run in a loop.

Comment: It breaks if you have a file like: `2"x4" lumber.txt`. This problem was the initial reason for building GNU Parallel.

Answer (score 0):

xargs helps you to execute commands on lines of the output like:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' | xargs mp3info
```

for every file found by find (i.e. output line)

```
mp3info <filename>
```

is executed

If you want to do something with the **whole** output of find, you don't need xargs at all.

Comment: If you have a file called `12" record from 1" tape.mp3` the above will fail. Substitute `xargs` with `parallel` and it will work.